# Query record categories if a no record has missing data in that category

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

Let's say I have the following data table:

```
id | data_1 | data_2 | category
1  |    a   |    A   |    1    
2  |    a   |    A   |    1    
3  |        |    B   |    2    
4  |    b   |    B   |    2    
5  |    b   |    B   |    2    
6  |    c   |        |    3    
7  |    c   |        |    3    
8  |    c   |    C   |    3    
9  |        |    D   |    4 
10 |    d   |        |    4    
11 |    d   |    D   |    4    
12 |    d   |    D   |    4    
13 |    e   |    E   |    5    
14 |    e   |    E   |    5     
15 |    f   |    F   |    6
```

and a list of (record) `id` as input:

```
1, 5, 12, 13, 14
```

I'd like to make a query which returns all those categories which are *"referenced"* by any of the record in the input list and the referenced category is *"complete"*.

By

- *referenced category* I mean that at least one record from the input list belongs to that category
- *complete category* I mean that all record that belongs to that category has value (i.e. not NULL or empty string) in both    *data_1* and *data_2* column. (So in the example table category 1, 5 and 6 is complete)

So for the example table and input the result would be:

```
category
   1    
   5
```

(And for an input of `4, 5, 6` the result would be `NULL` or empty list)

Is it possible to make single query for this?

([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/umfWTXoDtfMfR9yvsEgHTu/0))

Comment: create a https://dbfiddle.uk/Ho4tsJ0s with your setup and update your post with url

Comment: I just added the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, query `ids` where `category` is completed:

```sql
select
    category,
    array_agg(id) as ids
from tbl
group by category
having bool_and(nullif(data_1, '') || nullif(data_2, '') is not null) 
order by category;

 category |   ids
----------+---------
        1 | {1,2}
        5 | {13,14}
        6 | {15}
(3 rows)
```

Use this as a derived table to search `ids` matching the input list:

```sql
select category
from (
    select
        category,
        array_agg(id) as ids
    from tbl
    group by category
    having bool_and(nullif(data_1, '') || nullif(data_2, '') is not null) 
    ) s
where ids && array[1, 5, 12, 13, 14] -- input parameter
order by category;

 category
----------
        1
        5
(2 rows)
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HmKoaJkn).

Alternative solution using the `bool_and()` aggregate as a window function:

```sql
select distinct category
from (
    select 
        id, 
        category,
        bool_and(nullif(data_1, '') || nullif(data_2, '') is not null) over w as completed
    from tbl
    window w as (partition by category)
    ) s
where completed
and id = any(array[1, 5, 12, 13, 14]) -- input parameter
order by category;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct category from tbl 
where category not in (
select category from tbl
where data_1 is null or data_1 = ''
or  data_2 is null or data_2 = '')
```

Fixed using your fiddle!